# How to assign a template for a specific page

Tags: templates

I want to create a template for a specific page: the search result page.

I found the options to specify a template for an article or a page but not for a joomla system page.

Is possible to specify a template for the search page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It's possible.

You have to go to your Joomla administrator panel then:

1. Create a Search page (If you don't have one).
2. Create a Menu item for this search page( If you haven't created it yet).
3. Go to: Extensions > Templates > Styles
4. Select the checkbox of the template you want to be assigned to your search page and then click duplicate.
5. Click on the template you just duplicated.
6. Go to Menu Assignment tab.
7. On Menu Assignment, select the page you want the template to be assigned to.
8. Go to your `templates` folder, there you will find the duplicated template
9. You can edit the `index.php` file of this duplicated template to meet your needs.

You can do the same thing for any other page (error pages, etc)

If you want even more flexibility you can:

1. Go to: Extensions > Templates > Templates
2. Select the template you want to have a different look
3. Click on "Copy Template"
4. Choose the name of your template and click "Copy Template"